# Translating Python code to assembly

Tags: python, assembly, recursion, mips

In this current example above which I wrote, I used 80 as n. My output is n = 91, and count = 42. This is also known as McCarthy 91. However I would now like to use this code within assembly language(MIPS). Does anyone have any tips on how this might be done? I have never dealt with building a recursion type program in MIPS. Below I have supplied my working python code, and my assembly code with comments which is in the process of being wrote below the python code. Any tips/help will certainly be appreciate with the assembly code.

Python code:

```
   def mcc91(n):
        global count
        count +=1
        if n > 100:
            return n -10
        else:
            return mcc91 (mcc91(n + 11))


    def main():
        print mcc91(80)
        print count

    main()
```

MIPS PROGRAM

```
.data
    p1:
        .asciiz "What is integer n? "
    ans1:
        .asciiz "\nn is "
    ans2:
        .asciiz "\nCount is "


        .text
        .globl main

    main:
        li $v0, 4       # system call code for print_str
        la $a0, p1      # address of string to print
        syscall         # print the first prompt

        li $v0, 5       # system call code for read_int
        syscall         # read the first integer
        move    $t1, $v0    # and store it 'till later

        li $t9, 0       #tracks count

    loop1:
        bgt $t1, 100, target1
        add $t1, $t1, 11    #adds 11 when under 100
        add $t9, $t9, 1     #add 1 to count
        Loop1(loop1     #cluless how to do this

    target1:
        sub $t1, $t1, 10    #subtracts 10 when over 100
        add $t9, $t9, 1     #add 1 to count
        #j done         #cluless here also(how many stacks in is it? If 0, jump to done)

    done:
    #THIS PRINTS N
        li $v0, 4       # system call code for print_str
        la $a0, ans1        #address of string to print
        syscall         # print the answer identifying string

        li $v0, 1       # system call code for print_int
        move $a0, xxxxx     # integer to print (sum)
        syscall         # print it

    #THIS PRINTS Count
        li $v0, 4       # system call code for print_str
        la $a0, ans2        # address of string to print
        syscall         # print the answer identifying string

        li $v0, 1       # system call code for print_int
        move $a0, xxxxx     # integer to print (difference)
        syscall         # print it


        jr $ra          # return from this program to the system
```

Comment: Are you the same person who asked this question without any MIPS code, then deleted the question as soon as you got an answer? Or do you have multiple people taking a class that are all getting stuck on the same thing that the professor failed to explain?

Comment: Anyway, the answer that I gave there is the same here: Pick a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) that allows for reentrancy by using the stack as a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Then calling yourself recursively is exactly the same as calling any other function (just like it is in Python). That's all there is to it.

Comment: @abarnert this program is being done by 100+ students at my university. However, could you supply a further example?

Comment: Great, so your teacher didn't bother explaining how to implement functions in assembly, and then asked you to implement a recursive function? This is going to be a fun couple of days, as a few dozen of you come here with the same question… Anyway, I don't have any specific examples to give you, but the Wikipedia pages I linked are chock full of examples. Is there something you don't understand about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile python to C, then use a C compiler of your choice to get it down to assembly.